# AngularJS do not interpreted XSL in ng-click and ng-show

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, xslt

I have a web application where I combine XSL, XML and AngularJS. There is a tree structure and when clicking a leaf, it should appear a field in div tag with the content related to the specific leaf. Below the code.

The tree:

```
 <li>Root   
    <xsl:for-each select="//method[method_phase='Root']">
         <ul>
            <li><a ng-click="method.toShow='<xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>Field'"><xsl:value-of select="method_name"/></a></li>
         </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
</li>
```

And the field that should appear when clicking a leaf.

```
 <div ng-show="method.toShow=='<xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>Field'">

    div with content related to the leaf

 </div>
```

The problem by doing this is that it is not interpreted the xsl:value-of in the ng-click and ng-show. The error is the following:

```
The value of attribute "ng-click" associated with an element type "a" must not contain the '<' character
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Which angular version? 1.2 came with `$sce` which means *secure content escaping* I believe it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for how you currently try to set the **ng-click** attribute is not valid.

```
<a ng-click="method.toShow='<xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>Field'">
   <xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>
</a>
```

XSLT must be well-formed XML, and having a `<` and `>` in attribute values is not valid.

There are two ways to solve this. First is to use the **xsl:attribute** command to create the attribute.

```
<a>
   <xsl:attribute name="ng-click">method.toShow='<xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>Field'</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>
</a>
```

The second way is to use "Attribute Value Templates"

```
<a ng-click="method.toShow='{method_name}Field'">
   <xsl:value-of select="method_name"/>
</a>
```

The curly braces `{ }` here indicate an expression to be evaluated rather than output literally. This is probably the preferred way to do it, as it is less verbose, and much closer to how the HTML will actually be output.